# Why does this nested for-loop print this?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I need to figure out how this nested for-loop outputs:

```
1
2
3
2
4
2
3
5
2
3
4
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
    {
      cout << x << endl;
      for (y = 2; y < x; y++)
        cout << y << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: For each iteration of the first for loop, execution of the nested for loop happens.

Comment: The best way to figure it out is to walk through the code line by line. In that first `for` loop, `x` starts out as 1, so then it prints `1`, and gets to the next `for` loop, where `y` starts as 2, and then what happens? Is 2 less than 1? If not, what happens? And so on...

Comment: It's better to start a step in debugging here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't seem to understand which value is 'x' and which one is 'y':

You can easily understand this by replacing following lines of code:

```
cout << x << endl;
```

by

```
cout << "x: " << x << endl;
```

And

```
cout << y << endl;
```

by

```
cout << "y: " << x << endl;
```

Comment: Showing that result might help